# I need an effective way to store large amounts of similar information

Tags: java, oop

Currently I am using a super class (we'll call it `DataSuper`) that has variables for various information (e.g. A name, description, etc.). Various classes extend this super class and set the variables their specific details. The detail screen contains a generic `DataSuper` object and methods to set the information in the detail screen to variable set in the `DataSuper`. When a new instance of the detail screen is created it gets passed an int ID. It then uses a data grabber class (uses a switch and case with the int ID). The data grabber returns a sub class of `DataSuper`, which sets the information in the constructor and then the information on the detail screen is set.

What I'm asking is, is this a good method? I could possibly need 500+ subclasses of the `DataSuper` class to properly implement this method, and as far as speed/size of application is concerned is this an efficient method, or is there a better way?

Comment: The code better describes the code than your description. Post the code.

Comment: Do you really need to subclass each of the 500+ cases? Do they all have different types of fields or behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need a subclass when the only difference is the values of their superclass members? You could use the exactly same class with different values assigned to the members of multiple instances.

Comment: In most cases one will try to use the `Template method` and `Flyweight` pattern to get rid of the large number of classes and memory footprint.

Comment: This is what a Map is for.  A Map is essentially an object where the instance fields can be dynamically defined.

Answer (score 0):

There are several two "Design patterns" that help here:

1. Template method: instead of creating a large number of subclasses, try to create a hierarchy where each more concrete level tries to specify a part of the method even further.
2. If some attributes require a lot of space, but have a scarce set of possibilities, you might try to implement a Flyweight.

Furthermore what you describe sounds like a "bad smell":

It looks like you are implementing a "god class", a class that does all the stuff, try to separate the several responsibilities into several class hierarchies. You probably will pay a performance penalty, but today most computer scientists tend to think that development time is more expensive than running time.

Finally I doubt you need a superclass to store all data. In most cases some part of the data is only relevant to a small subset of the subclasses.

Answer (score -1):

it is difficult to understand without knowing the actual needs

But look at the design pattern to URL
http://www.oodesign.com/

They can guide you on design approaches :-)

Comment: +[a large amount] for suggesting design patterns. In most cases if you run into trouble its because you didn't considered them in the design.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.